# What does 0xFE mean in a C program?

Tags: c

In the given program below,

```
void main()
{

       int x=0xFE;

       int y=0xF3;
      .....
}
```

What values are assigned by `x=0xFE` and `y=0xF3`? What does `0x` represent?

Comment: Uhm.. [254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/254_%28number%29) and [243](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/243_%28number%29) ?

Comment: my pragmatical answer is: use `printf` :)

Answer (score 16):

Writing a value with `0x` before means it is written in [*hexadecimal notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), where the numbers 0-9 and additional "number" A-F are used to get a number system with the base 16. The big advantage of this is that each hexadecimal digit represents exactly 4 bits.

```
0xFE = 254
0xF3 = 243
```

So x = 254 and y = 243.

Comment: what value will be assigned in x and y?

Comment: @Nitin: the answer says it: x will be assigned 254, y will be assigned 243. `0xFE` and `254` are exactly the same number, only that `0xFE` is hexadecimal notation, and `254` is decimal notation. IOW, `0xFE`is just another way to write `254`. More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 6):

Numbers can be represented in different ways. In C, you can use decimal (e.g. 243), octal (e.g. 0363) or hexadecimal (0xF3).

If you write 243, you mean

```
243 = 2*10^2 + 4*10^1 + 3*10^0 = 2*100 + 4*10 + 3 = 243
```

where `^` means "to the power of". That means our normal numbers are base 10, or decimal. Hexadecimal uses base 16, and the digits are `0123456789ABCDEF`, where 0=0, ... 9=9, A=10, B=11, ... F=15. So 243 can also be written as

```
0xF3 = 15*16^1 + 3*16^0 = 15*16 + 3 = 243
```

That is what you see. In other words, 0xF3 is just another way to write 243, and 0xFE is another way to write 254 (15*16 + 14 = 254).

The advantage is that each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits, so 2 hexadecimal digits can be used to display a byte. If you know that 0x0 is 0000 in binary, and so on, up to 0xF, which is 1111 in binary, an experienced user can easily "see" the bits in a byte.

FWIW, octal is in base 8, so the only digits are 01234567. I have always found it a bit awkward to use.

Answer (score 2):

The values are in hexadecimal since they are preceded by the 0x identifier.
To convert the values, you can use your computer calculator on programmer mode or google.
http://screensnapr.com/v/aQEPYk.png

Comment: Doesn't anybody do base16-to-base10 conversions with pencil and paper anymore? :)

Comment: Doesn't anybody do it in their head anymore? It's pretty easy for 2-3 digits if you know your multiples of 16...

Comment: @R: Ok, quick, no cheating - what's 0x0D92 in decimal?